Blazor: Virtualize breaks @bind with inner components, what I do wrong?
I have a tree structure which has over 10.000 items.
I use Virtualize to lazy render items.
When I @bind tree state to item.
Then the connection between root and children is broken after the second level virtualized nodes.
Example:
| - level 1.1 // working
---- | level 2.1 // not working
---- ---- | level 3.1 // not working
---- | level 2.2 // not working
| - level 1.2 // working
---- | level 2.3 // not working

Tree state:
record TreeState(
   ITree Structure,
   INode SelectedNode
)

Tree root:
<h1>@State.SelectedNode.Id</h1>

@code {
    var TreeState State { get; set; }
    <ul>
        <Virtualize Items="@treeStructure" Context="node">
            <NodeComponent @key="node.Id" Node="@node" @bind-State="@State" />
        </Virtualize>
    </ul>
}

Tree node:
<li @onclick="@(() => SelectNode())">
    <b>Node.Name</b>
    @if(Node.HasChildren) {
        <ul>
            <Virtualize Items="@Node.Children" Context="node">
                <NodeComponent @key="node.Id" Node="@node" @bind-State="@State" />
            </Virtualize>
        </ul>
    }
</li>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public INode Node { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public TreeState State { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<TreeState> StateChanged { get; set; }

    private void SelectNode() {
        var newState = State with { SelectedNode = Node };
        StateChanged.InvokeAsync(newState); // This line is invoked correctly in debugger.
        // But the parent is never updated if click on second level of the tree and beyond.
    }
}

I already have an alternative for @bind therefore I am NOT interested in alternatives or workarounds.
How to make @bind work if clicked on the second level of nodes? Or at least I want to know if it is a bug from Microsoft or my misuse?

I'm pretty sure what you are attempting isn't supported by Virtualize.

@MrCakaShaunCurtis - can you please elaborate on this? The only thing I found in official documentation is that nested Virtualize is not forbidden. Beside, everything works as intended but @bind.

You're setting a property defined as a Parameter in the parent from a bind to the child.  That's a nono [ see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/overwriting-parameters?view=aspnetcore-8.0 ] in component design.  The value will be reset from the parent when it renders.  Can you devise a [MRE]?

@MrCakaShaunCurtis - Oh! You're half right, thank you! The problem is not that setting a property defined as a Parameter in the parent (its intended), but the fact that I'm not propagating further the event from the Child to Grandparent. This means I need somehow to detect when the child is seting the value to propagate it. Thanks a lot for pointing me toward the solution.

Thanks to @MrCakaShaunCurtis for pointing out the issue.
I'll leave my solution here in case someone would like to use @bind for consistency just like I do.
Tree node:
<li @onclick="@(() => SelectNode())">
    <b>Node.Name</b>
    @if(Node.HasChildren) {
        <ul>
            <Virtualize Items="@Node.Children" Context="node">
                <NodeComponent @key="node.Id" Node="@node" @bind-State="@ChildState" />
            </Virtualize>
        </ul>
    }
</li>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public INode Node { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public TreeState State { get; set; }

    [Parameter]
    public EventCallback<TreeState> StateChanged { get; set; }

    private TreeState ChildState
    { 
        get => State;
        set => StateChanged.InvokeAsync(value);
    }

    private void SelectNode() {
        var newState = State with { SelectedNode = Node };
        StateChanged.InvokeAsync(newState);
    }
}

